# Return number of users who are owners of docs in another collection (Meteor.js)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm looking to write a function that returns the number or count of unique users in the Meteor users collection, who are also owners of documents in another collection, called ServiceDesks.

For example, if there are 100 users (docs) in the 'users' collection, and there are 30 documents in the ServiceDesks collections, I'd like to return the count (30 or less unique users) of unique users who also are owners of the documents in the ServiceDesks collection.

How would I go about doing this?

OR

A lot simpler, how would I return the number of unique owners of the ServiceDesks collection.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: Agreed that something like ServiceDesks.distinct("users") is the most efficient way to do this.  Just note that you will need to add a package like mongodb-server-aggregation to support this server-side, and client-side it won't be available until minimongo adds support for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `owner` is a property of `ServiceDesks`, you could do this:

```js
var serviceDesks = ServiceDesks.find({}, {fields: {owner: 1}}).fetch();
var uniqueOwners = _.uniq(_.pluck(serviceDesks, 'owner'));
var count = uniqueOwners.length
```

Alternatively, if this only needs to run on the server, you could add the [mongodb-server-aggregation](https://atmospherejs.com/zvictor/mongodb-server-aggregation) package and do this:

```js
var count = ServiceDesks.distinct('owner').length
```